# Getting 403 forbidden with valid API key

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

I have a protected service, but I need to create links for sharing purpose. So I came over this feature:

```
new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
  AllowInHttpParams=true
},
```

I'm calling the service, getting the API directly from the ApiKey table, and in the debug console I can even see the SQL, which is correct (select where id, and id is my api key) and matches an active user, but still I'm getting a 403 from ServiceStack.

The `apikey` query param is used. Https is used (with valid CA signed cert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**403 Forbidden** indicates Authentication was successful (otherwise would return **401 unauthorized**) but the authenticated user does not have access to the resource, e.g. they don't have the required roles or permissions.

Comment: What I'm seeing in Postman (making sure to have cleared any cookies there) is:
Passing the API Key as Bearer token: Invalid key gives login page, valid key gives 403. Passing the API key in Query Params I get 403 no matter if key is valid or just junk.
When looking up they key in SQL I find my user, the only user, which works fine with credentials and JWT. The service has `[RequiredRole("Admin")]` which is the role my user has. Even if I remove the role I won't get access. If I login so the ss-cookies are set, then I can access the resource.

The Id column from the table is the one to use?

Comment: @specimen You're talking about 3 different types of authentication here, API Key, JWT and Credentials Server Session Auth. If authenticating with an API Key (and only an API Key) returns a 403, it's an indication it doesn't have the required role. You can intercept the role check by overriding the `HasRole()` in your Custom User Session, this is the [default implementation to check if the user has a role](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs#L106).

Comment: First I'd like to say it's such a privilege to have the main developer answer questions within minutes on SO even with time-zone difference. And it's been like that for years. *I found the solution:* I'm behind a reverse proxy, where SSL is terminated, so I had to add `RequireSecureConnection=false` to the ApiKeyAuthProvider settings. That made it work.